# Xcode 15 iOS 17 error: Failed to install the app on the device

Tags: xcode, xcode15, ios17

I am using Xcode 15.0.1 to build my iOS app. I'm using my physical device which is running iOS 17. When I try to run the app, a popup error says:

> Failed to install the app on the device.

It was working fine previously but randomly showed up. I haven't been able to run the app on my test device since.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an iOS 17 issue. The steps that worked for me:

- Disconnect iPhone from Mac
- On iPhone:

  - `Settings > Developer > Clear Trusted Computers`
  - **Uninstall the application**
- Reconnect iPhone to Mac
- In Xcode

  - `Window > Devices & Simulators`
  - You should see your device in the left sidebar
  - Re-pair the device

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. One note - I looked for a "Repair" button but I think you meant it as "Pair again"

Comment: @joel.d thanks for pointing that out - I edited it to remove confusion.

Comment: This, or a similar problem, is happening to me almost daily, and sometimes several times throughout one day. I can't possibly go through all of this every time. This is a huge time loss issue currently.